# How do I set my website's title to be equivalent to my iframe's title

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

It doesn't set the iframe title to the title of the webpage. What did i do wrong? If you'd like more detail please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>            
    window.onload = function() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const gameId = urlParams.get("id");

    fetch("games.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const game = data.find(item => item.id === gameId);
            
            if (game) {
                document.getElementById("game-iframe").src = game.url;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("game-player").innerHTML = "Invalid game ID.";
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });

    document.getElementById("game-iframe").addEventListener("load", function() {
        updateTitle();
    });
};

function updateTitle() {
    const gameId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("id");

    if (gameId === '9') {
        $( "iframe" ).on('load',function() {
    document.title = document.getElementById('game-iframe').contentDocument.title;
    });
    }
}
setInterval(updateTitle, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game-player">
        <iframe id="game-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting it to set the title of the iframe to the title of the webpage. It doesn't.

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main page? If not, you can't access its `contentDocument`.

Comment: It is, /game-hosting/9/index.html

Comment: What are you seeing instead of the title of the framed webpage?

Comment: just the url of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, I realised that it has to be hosted on the same server, I fixed that and it now works.

Comment: I asked you if they were, you said yes.

Comment: It was after I changed it.